Personalized Recommendations when Items have variants
In my ecommerce application, Items have two levels:

Product: Contains description, title, category and some attributes like brand.
Variant: Belongs to a Product and contains Stock Keeping Unit, images, price and some attributes like color or size.

When recommending an item I want it to have the title of the Product and the image and price of one of it's variants.
Of course, I could just recommend a variant ID and then look up the information of it's corresponding product. The problem arises when the model recommends many variants belonging to the same product. I will be left with less items to recommend as the filter happens outside of the Amazon Personalize Service.
Is there a way of overcoming this by having Amazon Personalize do the filter for me (not recommending more than one variant per product)?
Or is there another way I'm not seeing?
I don't want to worry about cases where most recommendations will be discarded and I'm left having to call the model again, wasting valuable time.

There are two approaches. Either model on parent items only in Personalize (the most common in retail) or model on variations/SKUs. If you model on parent items, select SKU level attributes that are most representative of the product to include in your items dataset. You may also want to consider putting variation attribute values like colors and sizes in categorical fields. This would allow you to filter on them too.
If you model on variations/SKUs but you want to recommend products, you will have to implement post-processing logic to collapse on the first variation recommended for each product. To make sure you have enough products to recommend, oversample Personalize by requesting more items than you need so you have enough products to work with. Since Personalize does not support pagination, making multiple calls doesn't work as it would with something like a database or search engine.
